Sending Outlook reminder email from Excel
I am trying to send a reminder email using Excel VBA. I am using Excel 2007 and Outlook 2007.
It is showing the email message in Outlook but the email has not been sent.
Here is the code:
Sub send_mail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim outmail As Object
    Dim mail_list As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo error_exit
    
    Set mail_list = Range(Range("D3"), Range("D3").End(xlDown))
    
    For Each cell In mail_list
        Set outmail = OutApp.createitem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With outmail
            .to = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .body = "Postovana " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Ovo je generisana poruka. Molim Vas da se javite na pregled." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Srdacan pozdrav" & vbNewLine & _
            "Dr"
            .send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set outmail = Nothing
        
    Next cell
    
    error_exit:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


See if this applies How to send mail when the .Send does not work?

You might also want to remove the On Error Resume Next line - don't hide errors, or you won't know what's broken.

The code only calls for displaying the draft email at the moment. If you replace the .display with .send inside the With statement, the email will be sent automatically.

Hello, I changed but it is showing messages in the Outlook and email has not been sen

If the newly create message is still shown in Outlook rather than silently sent, you still haven't changed ".display" to ".send"
